# Como somar dias a uma data com Moment.js?

Tags: typescript, data, momentjs

Estou tentando calcular o prazo do meu site em dias, ou seja, eu coloco "14 dias" e ele transforma em 00/00/0000.

Estou fazendo dessa forma, mas ela esta pegando a data completa e transformando em dias, quero fazer ao contrário, por exemplo:

Data atual: 08/07/2020 + Entrada (valor do input): 14 = saida esperada 22/07/2020.

```
onCalcularData(date: any): number {
    return Math.abs(
      moment()
        .startOf('day')
        .diff(moment(date).startOf('day'), 'days'),
    );
  }
```

Como chegar a isso?

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa. Dê um exemplo de entrada, saída esperada e saída atual.

Comment: Oi Rafael - seguindo sua proposta, eu preciso pegar a data atual e e preencher em um input um valor decimal, por exemplo: Data atual: 08/07/2020 + Entrada (valor do input): 14  = saida esperada 22/07/2020. Hoje eu faço o calculo pegando duas datas e as transformando em dias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para somar determinada quantidade de dias a uma data, basta usar [`add`](https://momentjs.com//docs/#/manipulating/add/):

```
onCalcularData(date: any, dias: number): moment.Moment {
    return moment(date).add(dias, 'days');
}
```

O retorno será um `Moment`. Mas se quiser retornar um [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), basta usar [`toDate()`](https://momentjs.com//docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/):

```
onCalcularData(date: any, dias: number): Date {
    return moment(date).add(dias, 'days').toDate();
}
```

Assim, se rodar com a data atual (08/07/2020) e somar 14 dias (`onCalcularData(new Date(), 14)`), o resultado será 22/07/2020. Lembrando que o horário será mantido (por exemplo, agora são 08:12 da manhã, então o resultado final será 22/07 no mesmo horário).

---

Aproveitando, acho que vale explicar dois conceitos importantes: datas e durações.

Uma data é um ponto específico no calendário. Por exemplo, 08/07/2020 representa o dia 8 do mês 7 do ano 2020 do calendário gregoriano.

Uma duração é uma quantidade de tempo. Por exemplo, "14 dias" - representa apenas um período, uma quantidade de tempo qualquer, mas sem qualquer relação com o calendário (a duração existe por si só, se eu disser somente "14 dias", não dá para saber quando começou ou terminou).

O que pode confundir é o fato de ambos usarem as mesmas palavras ("dia", "mês", etc), mas são coisas diferentes.

Só que esses dois conceitos estão relacionados. A diferença entre duas datas é uma duração (entre os dias 8 e 22, a diferença - ou a duração entre essas datas - é de 14 dias).

E se eu somar uma data com uma duração, o resultado é outra data (dia 8 + duração de 14 dias = dia 22).

O código da pergunta usa [`diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), que calcula a diferença entre duas datas e retorna uma duração. Mas você queria somar uma duração e uma data, e é para isso que `add` serve.

---

Complementando, se a ideia é somar **sempre** a partir da data atual, aí ficaria assim:

```
onCalcularData(dias: number): moment.Moment {
    return moment().add(dias, 'days');
}
```

Comment: Como seria rodar com NewDate? sou leiga em programação

Comment: @fernanda Do jeito que fiz, vc passa a data como parâmetro: `onCalcularData(new Date(), 14)`. Agora, se quer sempre somar 14 dias na data atual, aí a função seria apenas `onCalcularData(dias: number) { return moment().add(dias, 'days') }`

Comment: eu tentei fazer dessa forma  onCalcularData(newDate(), dias: number), porque os dias ficarão a criterio do usuario, porem recebo um erro do componente angular, por isso a pergunta

Comment: @fernanda `new Date()` tem um espaço depois do "new". De qualquer forma, se quer sempre somar na data atual, não precisa passá-la como parâmetro para a função. Atualizei a resposta com essa opção